# Emacs Style “artist-mode” for Xcode?

Tags: xcode, emacs

Is there anything that resembles Emacs' artist mode available for Xcode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a word - no :-) It's likely to only have limited use. Most developers would problably use gif/png images and reference them in a way that headerdoc/doxygen/appledoc can refer to when generating the documentation files.

Comment: OTOH, Artist mode + ditaa makes for much faster drawings than gif/png images.

Comment: I figured this was the case. Thanks for your answer.